# Pm2 dashboard does not show application logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, monitoring, pm2

I have a series of apis in node.js running on top of pm2. Now I'm monitoring them with the pm2 dashboard itself.
It turns out that when entering the apis through ssh I can view the application logs by running the command:
`pm2 logs`

However I cannot view these logs in pm2 dashboard. It keeps trying to load infinitely. Does anyone know how to enable this option or the correct way to view these logs in this dashboard ??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue here and what I found is, if you refresh the page after going to the realtime logs tab, it starts to show you the logs. ( Should report this to pm2 )

Answer (score -1):

Go to [app.pm2.io](https://app.pm2.io/)

- Select your bucket
- Click on the `Connect` button on top of the header
- Paste the `pm2 link` command in your terminal
- Still in the terminal `pm2 restart all`
- Refresh [app.pm2.io](https://app.pm2.io/) in your browser
- You're all set

Comment: The application is already linked to the users Dashboard. This answer doesn't explain how to show logs on app.pm2.io Dashboard to an already linked app.